# Angular 5, HTML, boolean on checkbox is checked

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Angular 5, Typescript 2.7.1

I can't seem to get the checkbox to be checked when returning a boolean, I've tried, `item.check` returns either true or false.

```
<tr class="even" *ngFor="let item of rows">
<input value="{{item.check}}" type="checkbox" checked="item.check">
```

The checkbox is always checked when checked is written inside input. And it does not get unchecked when `checked="false"`.

Is there a better way to do it with Angular features instead? like ngModel or ngIf???

Solution

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.check == 'true'">
```

Comment: assuming item is an object that contains a check boolean in your ts - use ngModel on your checkbox. `[(ngModel)]="item.check"`

Answer (score 181, accepted):

try:

```
[checked]="item.checked"
```

check out: [How to Deal with Different Form Controls in Angular](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2)

Comment: Thank you, i've tried but i needed to add <input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.check == 'true'"> then it works, thx

Comment: That is because your item.check is String not Boolean
item.check = true; //boolean
item.check = 'true'; //string

Comment: Since that blog is long gone, in case someone wants to read it [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210307151124/https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 30):

You can use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="record.status" (change)="changeStatus(record.id,$event)">
```

Here, record is the model for current row and status is boolean value.

Comment: how to extract boolean value from $event in ts component?

Comment: @svichkar for extracting you have to use **event.target.checked** value. if it's true , checkbox is checked, and unchecked otherwise.

Answer (score 24):

When you have a copy of an object the `[checked]` attribute might not work, in that case, you can use `(change)` in this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.selected" (change)="item.selected = !item.selected">
```

Answer (score 13):

Hope this will help somebody to develop custom checkbox component with custom styles. This solution can use with forms too.

**HTML**

```
<label class="lbl">

  <input #inputEl type="checkbox" [name]="label" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="onChange(inputEl.checked)"
   *ngIf="isChecked" checked>
  <input #inputEl type="checkbox" [name]="label" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="onChange(inputEl.checked)"
   *ngIf="!isChecked" >
  <span class="chk-box {{isChecked ? 'chk':''}}"></span>
  <span class="lbl-txt" *ngIf="label" >{{label}}</span>
</label>
```

**checkbox.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output, forwardRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxComponent),
  multi: true
};

/** Custom check box  */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkbox.component.scss'],
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {


  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() isChecked = false;
  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Output() getChange = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() className: string;

  // get accessor
  get value(): any {
    return this.isChecked;
  }

  // set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(value: any) {
    this.isChecked = value;
  }

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;


  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== this.isChecked) {
      this.isChecked = value;
    }
  }

  onChange(isChecked) {
    this.value = isChecked;
    this.getChange.emit(this.isChecked);
    this.onChangeCallback(this.value);
  }

  // From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  // From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {

  }

}
```

**checkbox.component.scss**

```
   @import "../../../assets/scss/_variables";
/* CHECKBOX */

.lbl {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #282828;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    &.checked {
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    &.focus {
      .chk-box{
        border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
        &.chk{
          border: none;
        }
      }
    }
    input {
        display: none;
    }

    /* checkbox icon */
    .chk-box {
        display: block;
        min-width: 15px;
        min-height: 15px;
        background: url('/assets/i/checkbox-not-selected.svg');
        background-size: 15px 15px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    input:checked+.chk-box {
        background: url('/assets/i/checkbox-selected.svg');
        background-size: 15px 15px;
    }
    .lbl-txt {
        margin-top: 0px;
    } 

}
```

**Usage**

Outside forms

```
<app-checkbox [label]="'Example'" [isChecked]="true"></app-checkbox>
```

Inside forms

```
<app-checkbox [label]="'Type 0'" formControlName="Type1"></app-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer,

In row.model.ts

```
export interface Row {
   otherProperty : type;
   checked : bool;
   otherProperty : type;
   ...
}
```

In .html

```
<tr class="even" *ngFor="let item of rows">
   <input [checked]="item.checked" type="checkbox">
</tr>
```

In .ts

rows : Row[] = [];

update the rows in component.ts

Answer (score 1):

**Work with checkboxes using observables**

You could even choose to use a `behaviourSubject` to utilize the power of observables so you can start a certain chain of reaction starting at the `isChecked$` observable.

In your component.ts:

```
public isChecked$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
toggleChecked() {
  this.isChecked$.next(!this.isChecked$.value)
}
```

In your template

```js
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked$ | async" (change)="toggleChecked()">
```

Answer (score 1):

[checked]= "isChecked"
This isChecked will be your varaible of type boolean in component.ts file i.e
if you setb isChecked variable to true in component.ts ts checkbox will be checked and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

<input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.checked == true">